# minikube on hyper-v VM cannot ping Windows 10 host

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v, minikube

I have read several posts and tried many different configurations but there must be something I'm missing.

I am trying to set up a dev environment on my Win 10 laptop using hyperv. I've had docker working on here with hyperv for a while. The docker VM uses an internal virtual switch named DockerNAT. When I launch an ubuntu container in docker it is able to ping the host machine and also is able to ping outside public network hosts as well as servers within my company network via the VPN.

The minikube VM, however, is not able to ping my host or other servers in my VPN. It is able to ping public internet sites. One of the apps I'm trying to deploy in the cluster needs to call a service on a system I have local on my laptop and I cannot seem to get it to work. This clearly wouldn't be the production configuration but I'd like to get it to work for POC/dev purposes.

```
> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : US-DM4LJM2-10
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : pbi.global.pvt
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : pbi.global.pvt
                                       pb.com
                                       ct.pb.com
                                       pitneybowes.ca
                                       g1.com
                                       pbi.hcs.int
                                       corpdom1.com
                                       ngsfac.corpdom1.com
                                       newgistics.com
                                       psi.psigroupinc.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : pb.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-05-9A-3C-7A-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.110.0.185(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.110.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 152.144.94.33
                                       152.144.94.50
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-01-25-2A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (minikubeExternal):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-9D-31-E6-DB-1F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.41(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, January 3, 2020 5:29:38 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, January 4, 2020 5:29:38 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-9D-31-E6-DB-20
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-9D-31-E6-DB-23
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

My docker VM uses the DockerNAT switch which is an Internal hyper-v switch. The minikubeExternal is an External switch in hyper-v bound to the wireless adapter. I have been unable to bind it to the Cisco AnyConnect VPN connection which I think may be my problem.

Get-VMNetworkAdapter returns:

```
Name            IsManagementOs VMName          SwitchName       MacAddress   Status                      IPAddresses
----            -------------- ------          ----------       ----------   ------                      -----------
Network Adapter False          DockerDesktopVM DockerNAT        00155D01252B {Degraded, ProtocolVersion} {}
Network Adapter False          minikube        minikubeExternal 00155D01253A {Ok}                        {192.168.1.43, fe80::215:5dff:fe01:253a}
```

To test the ability to see the host from within the minikube cluster, I issue the `minikube ssh` command and try to ping the host IP. I've tried to ping the IP address of the host as well as the IP of the minikubeExternal switch and neither works (ping just hangs).

I have also tried this without the VPN connected and I get the same results. Since the DockerNAT is internal and is able to ping both the host and public internet I tried making the minikube VM switch also an internal switch and I even tried just using the DockerNAT switch and none of those worked.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
> minikube version
minikube version: v1.6.2
commit: 54f28ac5d3a815d1196cd5d57d707439ee4bb392
> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Co
mpiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Co
mpiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Did you try to connect your minikube to `Default Switch` in Hyper-V? It should connect you to the NAT of Windows 10 and it should grant you ability to connect to host (Windows 10) and use NAT to access other things outside your laptop. When I tried it I did not provide `--hyperv-virtual-switch` parameter in `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv` and it used the default one.

Comment: I don't have a default switch. After removing the external switch I created for minikueb, I am left with two switches: DockerNAT and one called Layered_Wi-Fi. I tried starting minikube on each of these. It wouldn't start with Layered_Wi-Fi and it failed with a socket ssh exception and the DockerNAT switch hung and failed to start which I think is odd since the docker machines on the docker VM that also uses this switch are able to access the internet.